# Finding the best knapsack solver

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am looking for the stat-of-the-art solver for the 0-1 knapsack problem,
Do any one know how to find such a solver?
better if it will be written in python or matlab.

Do you know what is limitation of current solver?

Thanks
Tomer

Comment: The Knapsack problem is *pseudo-polynomial*, and therefore dynamic programming will often be sufficient. There is not that much focus on the simple 0-1 KP anymore. Other variants, like the quadratic knapsack problem, are often more challening.

Comment: Is it true that the dynamic programming can work only with integer weights and values?

Answer (score 1):

In 2019, Google's or-tools won 4 of 5 "gold medals" in the mini zinc challenge.

They nicely present how to solve knapsack among other things in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/knapsack?hl=de). They have python bindings as well.

I'm not a mathematician, but I use these tools and they are really good for developers, IMHO.